# Installing on multiple drive

Tags: linux, debian

I have a 500GB ssd and 250GB ssd in my laptop. I have installed linux where / and /home everything in a single drive. I want to install linux in a drive and also install application on other drive also. What should I do for that and what type of partition I have to follow?

Comment: Are you looking for LVM perhaps? Its a bit unclear what you're asking, [edit] your question and provide more details please (for example, how you want your partitions to be set up in the end).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to install linux in a drive and also install application on
> other drive also.

Your question is essentially the same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313592/how-to-install-applications-to-a-separate-hdd) Ask Ubuntu question, and I can't improve on the answers provided there.

I'll instead answer with a question for you to consider - why?

What benefit do you hope to gain from doing so, and does it really out weight the negatives and potential headaches it may cause you down the road (e.g. drive failure)?

I instead strongly suggest you put the OS/Programs on one drive (root /), and partition the other drive as /home. Whether or not you have a swap partition (or file) is up to you (for my laptop, I prefer a swap file on a cheap SD card, as I have plenty of memory in my laptop (8Gb), with kernel swappiness set low. This saves a lot of writes to my root SSD - more info on this in the link below).

With root/home split between the drives, if your OS goes boom!, at least you have all your config files and personal data on a separate drive and can easily reinstall your OS/Programs again, with everything basically restored to the way it was. Or if the /home drive fails, you (being a responsible PC user) can easily restore your /home drive from backups, and be back up and running in no time.

If however one drive failed in some way with apps split, that could be a pain to restore.

So again, I'd suggest move your /home dir to the second drive (there are plenty of tutorials out there for moving /home), or it may be better to just reinstall from scratch...

Namely because I'm assuming you installed Debian 10 Stable (Buster), whereas Debian 11 Testing (Bullseye) has a stable release just around the corner (could be any day now!). And there's nothing worse then just completing your dream build, then having to do an upgrade shortly after. So you could wait for its release, or you might want to try installing the [Bullseye RC 2 release](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/)... you can use either the official, weekly or daily build (I'd just go the latest daily). Although this is still technically testing, once officially released, your install should just rollover to being stable (just make sure your /etc/apt/sources.list sources point to 'bullseye' not 'testing').

And I'd also suggest you take a look at the [Debian Wiki SSD Optimization](https://wiki.debian.org/%20SSDOptimization%20) page. Lots of good info on how to squeeze as much life/performance out of your SSD's.

Happy hacking! :-)

EDIT: I forgot to mention a rather simple solution here; use [AppImage's](https://appimage.org/) (you can store these wherever you want) and/or [Snaps](https://snapcraft.io/) (I believe the default /var/lib/snapd/snaps directory can be relatively easily changed).